# {% block something %} always being displayed despite being False in an if-statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two types of blog articles. Regular blog articles, and translation articles. They both have different html markup. I have a boolean variable `translation_bool` in my models to check if it is a translation article or not. If it is I want it to display my `{% block translation %}` and if not `{% block translation %}`. It worked with plain html code and not using html tags. But I had so much reusable code that it got troublesome to manage.

So my question is: why is this happening despite it being inside of an if statement.

**Article template**:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block js %}...{% endblock %}

{% if blogpost.translation_bool == True %}
        {% block translation %}....{% endblock %}
{% else %}
        {% block content %}...{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block sidebar %}....{% endblock %}
```

In **Base Generic Template**:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">

            {% block content %}{% endblock %}

            {% block translation %}{% endblock %}

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        {% block social_media %}...{% endblock %}
        {% block sidebar %}...{% endblock %}
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because blocks not defined in child template will render value from parent template. So in your case you should perform validation inside parent template. Or if it's impossible override blocks in child with empty content:

```
{% block translation %}
    {% if blogpost.translation_bool == True %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if blogpost.translation_bool == False %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Note `{{ block.super }}` will render content from parent template.

Comment: Thank you. I had to edit the code but I understand how it works. Thank you so much for your time and explanation.